# AudioKit automatically enabling Microphone capture

Tags: swift, macos, audiokit

So I found out that AudioKit is automatically enabling Microphone capture upon `AudioKit.start`. This also happens in the Playgrounds and is 100% reproducible.

Turning off AKSettings.audioInputEnabled does not seem to help. Besides the fact that it looks like a security risk to any user using MicroSnitch or similar, it also produces problems with BlueTooth Audio, which may automatically downsample for a lot of connections if microphone input is enabled.

Is there another way to turn this off?